# Can I ask what the definition of "enterprise services" is?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, terminology

Can I ask this here? If not, what other stack exchange site would best?

---

[Apple’s New Era Has Begun](https://redd.it/i74qev)

> Now Apple has set its sights on a much larger bite of the apple: **enterprise services**. It’s such a lucrative industry that Apple’s CEO, Tim Cook, calls it the “mother of all opportunities.”

I Googled "enterprise services", but I don't understand these two complicated explanations.

[What is Enterprise Services? - Definition from Techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25404/enterprise-services)

> ### Definition - What does *Enterprise Services* mean?
>
> Enterprise services is an over-arching term to describe an architecture combining engineering discipline and computer science to solve practical business problems. Enterprise services architecture generally includes high-level components and principles of object-oriented design employed to match the current heterogeneous world of IT architecture.
>
> ### Techopedia explains *Enterprise Services*
>
> The concept of enterprise services was created in 2002 by Hasso Plattner, the chairman of SAP AG. Enterprise services architecture includes layers of components aggregating data and application functions from applications, which creates reusable elements, which are also called modules. The components use enterprise services for communication. Enterprise services architecture minimizes the complexity of the connections among the components to facilitate reuse. The enterprise services architecture allows deployment of Web services to create applications within the current infrastructure, increasing business value.
>
> Enterprise services architecture emphasizes abstraction and componentization, which provides a mechanism for employing both the required internal and external business standards. The main goal of enterprise services architecture is to create an IT environment in which standardized components can aggregate and work together to reduce complexity. To create reusable and useful components, it is equally important to build an infrastructure allowing components to conform to the changing needs of the environment.

[What is Enterprise Services | IGI Global](https://www.igi-global.com/dictionary/enterprise-services/9998)

> ## What is Enterprise Services
>
> 1. are “a standards-based way of encapsulating **enterprise** functionality and exposing it as a reusable business service that can be combined with other **services** to meet new requirements. **Enterprise services**, defined by SAP and its partners and customers, can be assembled together to compose new applications or enable new business processes.” (Source: **Enterprise Services** Wiki, Service Oriented Architecture) [Learn more in: What is SAP Business Blueprint?](https://www.igi-global.com/chapter/sap-business-blueprint/20269)
> 2. Are reusable business **services** which **enterprise** functionality is encapsulated in a standards-based way. The **enterprise services** are reusable business **services** that can be combined with other **services** to meet new requirements. **Enterprise services** can be assembled together to compose new applications or enable new business processes. [Learn more in: Internet Enterprise Service Design Based on Existing Architectural Knowledge](https://www.igi-global.com/chapter/internet-enterprise-service-design-based-on-existing-architectural-knowledge/149004)
> 3. Highly-integrated web **services** combined with business logic and semantics that can be accessed and used repeatedly to support a particular business process. [Learn more in: Situational Enterprise Services](https://www.igi-global.com/chapter/situational-enterprise-services/149007)

Comment: This would not be on topic for the main site as it is to do with company definitions and not computer hardware or software.

Comment: @mokubai what other sub bests this?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks! if this migrates, i accept your answer!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This would not be on topic for the main site as it is to do with company definitions and not computer hardware or software.

"What does *word* mean?" Or "How do I use *words or phrase*?" Would be on topic at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), but I suspect that defining company types would be off topic there and you would have to ask their meta.

It wouldn't surprise me if we didn't have a site for this type of question at all. Not all questions have a place at Stack Exchange.